# AWS SAM-template not able to split comma separated list of string from AWS SSM parameter store

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, aws-serverless

I have created a vpc and security group with terraform and stored the values on the ssm parameter store

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "private_subnets" {
  name = "/infra/vpc/private_subnets"
  type = "String"  
  value = join(",", module.vpc.private_subnets) 
}


resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "sg" {
  name = "/infra/vpc/sg"
  type = "String" 
  value = aws_security_group.lambda.id
  
}
```

with sam-template I am trying to deploying a lambda function on the private subnet

```
Globals:
  Function:
    Runtime: java11 
    Timeout: 20
    Architectures:
      - x86_64
    MemorySize: 512
    VpcConfig:
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - '{{resolve:ssm:/infra/vpc/sg}}'
      SubnetIds: !Split [ ",", '{{resolve:ssm:/infra/vpc/private_subnets}}' ]
```

But the sam is not able to split the string of private subnets to  list of private subnets.

The error is

> validation error detected: Value
> '[subnet-aaaaaa,subnet-bbbbb,subnet-cccccc]' at 'vpcConfig.subnetIds'
> failed to satisfy constraint: